# If else not working with datetime in python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

**Background**

I have a dataframe df. It has order_dates for customers(when was transaction done etc. I am trying to create a new column recent which will have 1 if the transaction was recent(within 1 month from today) and 0 if it is not a recent transaction.

e.g.

Current df

```
 order_date
 2019-01-01
 2019-12-14
 2019-10-12
 2019-11-22
```

Output df needed

```
 order_date   recent
 2019-01-01    0
 2019-12-14    1
 2019-10-12    0
 2019-11-22    0
 2019-12-09    1
```

**Code:**

```
   import datetime
   df['recent'] = 9
   df['order_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['order_date']).dt.date

   if ((df['order_date']) >(datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(1*365/12))).any():
    df['recent'] == 1
   else:
    df['recent'] == 0
```

I wrote default value 9 for recent because if else was not working and now I am getting all 9 values in df['recent']

**Some basic background:**

```
[IN]:print(df['order_date'].loc[0])
2019-01-01
[IN]:type(df['order_date'])
pandas.core.series.Series
[IN]:print(datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(1*365/12))
2019-12-01
[IN]:type(datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(1*365/12))
datetime.date
```

Comment: how can row 2 be 1 when the transaction was in october? it was more than 50 days ago only row 1 should be a 1

Comment: corrected @Datanovice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert boolean mask to integers by [`Series.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
df['order_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['order_date']).dt.date
#solution for oldier pandas versions
#df['order_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['order_date']).dt.floor('d')


m = (df['order_date']) >(datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(1*365/12))

df['recent'] = m.astype(int)
```

Or set values by [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['recent'] = np.where(m, 1, 0)
```

Comment: Hi this works. Thanks. But how to make it work with if else.

Comment: @ShailajaGuptaKapoor - If use `any()` like in question it means if at least one True in mask `m` set `df['recent']` to`1` - all values, else set all values to `0`. So if want set correct way in pandas values by condition use `numpy.where`, it is numpy/pandas alternative for `if-else` statement.